# Userform initialisation

Tags: vba, excel, userform

In my Userform Initialisation, I have set the value of optionbutton1 and optionbutton4 as true by default. There are four option buttons. If the user clicks any other option button, I want the following to be the chart caption.

I have called ths sub procedure in relation to the command button:

```
Sub ChartName()
    If UserForm1.OptionButton1.value = True And UserForm1.OptionButton3.value = True Then
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "First Case"
    ElseIf UserForm1.OptionButton2.value = True And UserForm1.OptionButton3.value = True Then
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Second Case"
    ElseIf UserForm1.OptionButton1.value = True And UserForm1.OptionButton4.value = True Then
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Third Case"
    ElseIf UserForm1.OptionButton2.value = True And UserForm1.OptionButton4.value = True Then
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Fourth Case"
End Sub
```

However, no matter what the user selects, the default optionbutton1 and optionbutton3 is taken as true and hence always "First Case" is displayed.

Can someone suggest to me how this can be fixed?

Comment: If / ElseIf structures will take the first case that works. Since you told us that by default the optionbuttons are true, it simply enters the first case. Have them be false by default and check what happens then.

Comment: First, are you sure that upon clicking the Option buttons, this code runs in background. Second, in place of ActiveChart try naming it with proper convention such as. Sheets("Sheet1").Charts("Chart 1")

Comment: If I have them false, the command button is not atall reading the sub procedure. Usually its a common practice to set some default and later alter is the user changes something. I dont understand why is it not working.

Comment: @Vasim: Tried, still taking just the first line. And yes it is reaching the sub-procdure for sure, since on commenting the sub-procedure no title is displayed on the chart.

Comment: Do you have these option buttons in different frames? I thought option buttons on a form or within a frame on a form were "mutually exclusive". That is, you click one then the previously selected one is set to FALSE (i.e. it's de-selected).

Comment: Yes I have optionbutton 1 and optionbutton 3 in one frame and optionbutton 2 and optionbutton 4 in the other frame.

Comment: You can use ```GroupName``` property to distinguish between groups of particular option button.

Comment: The thing is the above used code, works in every other context in the entire code. For example, with the same selection criteria, I have selected some data from the sheets. I tried and saw that it works fine. It just doesnt work for the chart title.

Comment: You have two action. First IF operator, second ASSIGN operator. I think the error is in IF operator, I don't understand how you set optionbutton to work independently! To test that set breakpoint on all ASSIGN operator and see what ASSIGN operator works. I test ASSIGN operator ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "First Case" - it works! Some trouble must be when you have not ActiveChart!!  When it works why second ASSIGN not set value only that IF not allow to go there. TEST YOUR IF operator!

Comment: @Ivan: yeah I think something is related to stating ActiveChart. .... four times and it takes only the first time. As my If structure worked for other selection cases, I simple declared a string variable and added "First case" , "second case" and so on with the existing if structure that works, and finally at the end of graph plot I just stated one time for graph title as that string. Strangely this worked. Nevertheless, thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score -1):

Not knowing as much about your situation as i would hope. Try this:

```
Sub ChartName()
    If UserForm1.OptionButton1.Value = True And UserForm1.OptionButton3.Value = True Then
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "First Case"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If UserForm1.OptionButton2.Value = True And UserForm1.OptionButton3.Value = True Then
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Second Case"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If UserForm1.OptionButton1.Value = True And UserForm1.OptionButton4.Value = True Then
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Third Case"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If UserForm1.OptionButton2.Value = True And UserForm1.OptionButton4.Value = True Then
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Fourth Case"
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: IF this answered your question please mark as answered.